# Alert before redirect showing value with message in asp

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to display a string along with the message.But i get an error.
str1 is a value retrieved from a table

the code is

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirect", "alert('Welcome'); window.location='" +
         Request.ApplicationPath + "#';", true);
```

but i want to display it as follows

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirect", "alert('Welcome '" + tbEmail.Text + "''); window.location='" +
         Request.ApplicationPath + "#';", true);
```

I'm just a beginner,any help is appreciated ,thank you

Comment: What error? post error also.

Comment: you missed a `"` .. after the `)` and have a extra `'`...use this  `"alert('Welcome '" + tbEmail.Text + "')";`

Comment: its showing this red underline http://i63.tinypic.com/2lvbihw.jpg